# querying for records syntax, returns AdapterPopulatedRecordArray which I have no idea how to use

Tags: ember.js

I'm using the querying for records functionality from the guides here:

http://emberjs.com/guides/models/finding-records/

my route looks like this:

> App.CatchallRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
>       model: function(params) {
>           var _self = this;
>           return _self.store.find('article', {
>               urlSegment: params.url
>           });
>       }
>   });

unlike the times when I'm not passing an object as a 2nd param to find, I end up with this AdapterPopulatedRecordArray which then I have no idea what to do with to get my data into the template. Does anyone have a solution for this?